# Issue in AjaxPost / WebMethod .

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a WebMethod that works perfectly fine locally.

I have updated the code on a free hosting provider and some how the Method does not work any more i am always getting.

```
Unknown web method saveformdata/.
```

To see the page please [Click here](http://questionaires.freeasphost.net) . I have tried multiple step but every time it works fine locally but not online.

```
METHOD : Default.aspx.cs

  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public static string saveformdata(string html)
    {
        string messagetxt = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            html = "<html><body><div id=\"formText\" style=\"margin:0 auto; width:700px; font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#3f3f3f; font-size:12px; \">" + html + "</div></body></html>";
            long milliseconds = (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) / 1000;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int x = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
            int y = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
            int z = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
            milliseconds = milliseconds + x + y + z;


            string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Questionaires");

            File.WriteAllText(path + "\\" + milliseconds + "_form.html", html);
            messagetxt = "Form Saved Successfully. Thank you for your time.";
            return messagetxt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messagetxt = ex.ToString();
        }

        return messagetxt;
    }


METHOD : Default.aspx

function saveForm()
    {
        var bodytag = document.getElementById("formText");
        var html = bodytag.innerHTML;

        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'html': html });

        //PageMethods.saveform(html, Success,callerMethod_Failure);

          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
              url: "Default.aspx/saveformdata",
              data: dataToSend,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccessAjax,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
        });

    }

    function OnSuccessAjax(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Thank you

Comment: What does "not work any more" mean? Tell us what happens, detail any errors.

Comment: I am always getting : Unknown web method saveformdata

Comment: That's it? OK, did it ever work? If not can you verify you deployed what you think you deployed?

Comment: It never worked that is what i said in the question always works locally never online.

Comment: Then it is probably an environmental issue, not code. There are plenty of things that can go wrong with server connections and web servers that are not related to the code in the application, unless you have not deployed the same code that you are running locally.

Comment: adding `/` before Default.aspx in ajax url should solve the problem

Comment: nope same thing @ElyasEsna

Comment: To add to what @Crowcoder is talking about, some code requires full trust environment to work online but some hosts only have partial trust environments.